# Likelihood of collision using most significant bits of a UUID in Java

Tags: java, collision, uuid

If I'm using `Long uuid = UUID.randomUUID().getMostSignificantBits()` how likely is it to get a collision. It cuts off the least significant bits, so there is a possibility that you run into a collision, right?

Answer (score 223, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html), the static method `UUID.randomUUID()` generates a type 4 UUID.

This means that six bits are used for some type information and the remaining 122 bits are assigned randomly.

The six non-random bits are distributed with four in the most significant half of the UUID and two in the least significant half. So the most significant half of your UUID contains 60 bits of randomness, which means you on average need to generate 2^30 UUIDs to get a collision (compared to 2^61 for the full UUID).

So I would say that you are rather safe. Note, however that this is absolutely not true for other types of UUIDs, as Carl Seleborg mentions.

Incidentally, you would be slightly better off by using the least significant half of the UUID (or just generating a random long using SecureRandom).

Comment: I'm not sure this is entirely correct - looking at the implementation, it is clear that the version / variant information is not stored in the most significant bits, but rather somewhere in the middle.

Comment: @RasmusFaber The comment by [Tom](http://stackoverflow.com/users/223201/tom) is correct: The Answer here is **incorrect about the six most significant bits** being type information. There are indeed six bits of non-random data but four bits identify the Version 4 and two other bits are reserved. The four and two bits are located in different positions near the middle of the 128-bit value. See the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29).

Answer (score 58):

Raymond Chen has a really excellent blog post on this:

[GUIDs are globally unique, but substrings of GUIDs aren't](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080627-00/?p=21823)

Comment: The link is not dead any more.

Comment: The link is dead once again. Here's a link to a [web archive version](http://web.archive.org/web/20081211233221/http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/06/27/8659071.aspx).

Answer (score 13):

I thinks this is the best example for using randomUUID :

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=56

Answer (score 10):

You are better off just generating a random long value, then all the bits are random. In Java 6, new Random() uses the System.nanoTime() plus a counter as a seed.

There are different levels of uniqueness.

If you need uniqueness across many machines, you could have a central database table for allocating unique ids, or even batches of unique ids.

If you just need to have uniqueness in one app  you can just have a counter (or a counter which starts from the currentTimeMillis()*1000 or nanoTime() depending on your requirements)

Answer (score 7):

Use Time `YYYYDDDD` (Year + Day of Year) as prefix. This decreases database fragmentation in tables and indexes. This method returns `byte[40]`. I used it in a hybrid environment where the Active Directory SID (`varbinary(85)`) is the key for LDAP users and an application auto-generated ID is used for non-LDAP Users. Also the large number of transactions per day in transactional tables (Banking Industry) cannot use standard `Int` types for Keys

```
private static final DecimalFormat timeFormat4 = new DecimalFormat("0000;0000");

public static byte[] getSidWithCalendar() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    String val = String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    val += timeFormat4.format(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
    val += UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-", "");
    return val.getBytes();
}
```

Comment: Why not use a standard V1 UUID instead?