# How to create a UUID or GUID in Java 1.4

Tags: java, uuid

I need to create a UUID or GUID in java 1.4.  I get a classnotfound exception when i use: java.util.UUID.

There are similar questions here linked below, but none answer with a generator for Java 1.4:

- [Likelihood of collision using most significant bits of a UUID in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325443/generate-uuid-in-java)
- [Create a GUID in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982748/create-a-guid-in-java)

I have also found a few classes online:

- http://johannburkard.de/software/uuid/
- http://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/1.4/org/apache/jackrabbit/uuid/UUID.html

What would you suggest I use to create a UUID or GUID in java 1.4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose there is no chance convincing the client to get off an unsupported version of Java? Which if the answer is no then your only recourse is to use/modify one of the open source implementations from the web. You mentioned two of them in your question, another one you might want to look at is [JUG](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JugHome).

And oh yea, your reference to java.util.UUID failed because it's only available in Java 5 and up.

Good luck!

Comment: Yeah i wish I could use a later version, unfortunately the technology is restriced by SAP ISA.  I will check out JUG and let you know how it goes.  

Thanks.

Comment: I actually ended up using johannburkards uuid - http://johannburkard.de/software/uuid/.  I trialed it first and found no issue with getting started and it seems to work well.

Comment: I tried johannburkards uuid just now, but the current 3.2 release is for JDK5 and therefore no longer works as a JDK 1.4 UUID generator.

Comment: after years since this question was asked, about a technology that was already outdated then, it's unbelievable that some of us still need to check into this stuff, since there is still legacy code using j2ee 1.4 - i just tried to compile commons-id and though it wasn't easy for me, i found it afterwards that it needs an XML settings file - since i didn't want to invest yet more time into the internals of UUIDs, i used retrotranslator (see some other questions here) to convert a small auxiliary JAR file I created with JDK 1.5, into 1.4, and saw it work well.

Answer (score 3):

java.util.UUID was added to JDK since 1.5.

For a simple lightweight implementation, take a look at this blog post: http://lzkyo.iteye.com/blog/453120.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Commons ID (sandbox project, so you have to build from source, but I've used it and it works): [project page](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/id/), [svn repo](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/sandbox/id/trunk/src/java/org/apache/commons/id/uuid/)

You can also check try [this project](http://johannburkard.de/software/uuid/) but I haven't used it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the TechKey functionality within SAP ISA.  that is what it is there for.  Also it is compatiable with the ABAP Tables and well as any Portal and SAP J2EE Tables.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the UUID class is available since 1.5. I just implemented this utility class that creates UUIDs as **String**. Fell free to use and share. I hope it helps someone else!

```java
package your.package.name;

import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Utility class that creates random-based UUIDs as Strings.
 * 
 */
public abstract class RandomUuidStringCreator {

    private static final int RANDOM_VERSION = 4;

    /**
     * Returns a random-based UUID as String.
     * 
     * It uses a thread local {@link SecureRandom}.
     * 
     * @return a random-based UUID string
     */
    public static String getRandomUuid() {
        return getRandomUuid(SecureRandomLazyHolder.SECURE_RANDOM);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a random-based UUID String.
     * 
     * It uses any instance of {@link Random}.
     * 
     * @return a random-based UUID string
     */
    public static String getRandomUuid(Random random) {

        long msb = 0;
        long lsb = 0;

        // (3) set all bit randomly
        if (random instanceof SecureRandom) {
            // Faster for instances of SecureRandom
            final byte[] bytes = new byte[16];
            random.nextBytes(bytes);
            msb = toNumber(bytes, 0, 8); // first 8 bytes for MSB
            lsb = toNumber(bytes, 8, 16); // last 8 bytes for LSB
        } else {
            msb = random.nextLong(); // first 8 bytes for MSB
            lsb = random.nextLong(); // last 8 bytes for LSB
        }

        // Apply version and variant bits (required for RFC-4122 compliance)
        msb = (msb & 0xffffffffffff0fffL) | (RANDOM_VERSION & 0x0f) << 12; // apply version bits
        lsb = (lsb & 0x3fffffffffffffffL) | 0x8000000000000000L; // apply variant bits

        // Convert MSB and LSB to hexadecimal
        String msbHex = zerofill(Long.toHexString(msb), 16);
        String lsbHex = zerofill(Long.toHexString(lsb), 16);

        // Return the UUID
        return format(msbHex + lsbHex);
    }

    private static long toNumber(final byte[] bytes, final int start, final int length) {
        long result = 0;
        for (int i = start; i < length; i++) {
            result = (result << 8) | (bytes[i] & 0xff);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static String zerofill(String string, int length) {
        return new String(lpad(string.toCharArray(), length, '0'));
    }

    private static char[] lpad(char[] chars, int length, char fill) {

        int delta = 0;
        int limit = 0;

        if (length > chars.length) {
            delta = length - chars.length;
            limit = length;
        } else {
            delta = 0;
            limit = chars.length;
        }

        char[] output = new char[chars.length + delta];
        for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
            if (i < delta) {
                output[i] = fill;
            } else {
                output[i] = chars[i - delta];
            }
        }
        return output;
    }

    private static String format(String string) {
        char[] input = string.toCharArray();
        char[] output = new char[36];

        System.arraycopy(input, 0, output, 0, 8);
        System.arraycopy(input, 8, output, 9, 4);
        System.arraycopy(input, 12, output, 14, 4);
        System.arraycopy(input, 16, output, 19, 4);
        System.arraycopy(input, 20, output, 24, 12);

        output[8] = '-';
        output[13] = '-';
        output[18] = '-';
        output[23] = '-';

        return new String(output);
    }

    // Holds lazy secure random
    private static class SecureRandomLazyHolder {
        static final Random SECURE_RANDOM = new SecureRandom();
    }

    /**
     * For tests!
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("// Using thread local `java.security.SecureRandom` (DEFAULT)");
        System.out.println("RandomUuidCreator.getRandomUuid()");
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(RandomUuidStringCreator.getRandomUuid());
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("// Using `java.util.Random` (FASTER)");
        System.out.println("RandomUuidCreator.getRandomUuid(new Random())");
        System.out.println();
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(RandomUuidStringCreator.getRandomUuid(random));
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
// Using `java.security.SecureRandom` (DEFAULT)
RandomUuidStringCreator.getRandomUuid()

'c4d1b0ec-c03a-4430-b210-bd692456d8f4'
'ddad65fb-aef9-4309-842d-284cef70e5f6'
'8b37cd8c-7390-4683-abed-524f97626995'
'd84b19bd-1fdb-4d76-ab7a-a845939c6934'
'ddb48e15-9512-4802-ace9-724d766643c6'

// Using `java.util.Random` (FASTER)
RandomUuidStringCreator.getRandomUuid(new Random())

'fa0a4861-6fa0-4258-8c8d-c89db9730b3e'
'bfe794fa-fe34-4ec3-aa93-5ec2e0897150'
'4c6441d8-10b5-4d8e-8dcf-6f1889d675e1'
'6f3012b7-e846-4173-8ffc-3a6e41893ea7'
'b73125a8-60f1-4dfd-b9fe-1a27aeb133a8'
```