# Unique Id's in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generate UUID in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325443/generate-uuid-in-java)
>   [Create a GUID in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982748/create-a-guid-in-java)

I am using below snippet for generating unique id's

```
String id = Long.toString(System.nanoTime());
```

Problem is it generates same id till 1 min.

Is there any other way to generate unique id's?

Comment: You're saying your JRE's `nanoTime` implementation generates the same value for an entire minute?! Is your `currentTimeMillis` equally broken? Still voting to close, but that's pretty messed up.

Answer (score 5):

There is a UUID class on the `java.util` package.

```
String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

UUID.randomUUID()

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html