# Strategy to generate auto increment unique number in CQ

Tags: aem

I have a requirement to create CQ pages programmatically. But the challenge is that the page name/uri should be autogenerated combination of a string + unique number (eg. PT2000, PT2001).

Can someone tell me a way way to generate an autoincrement-id/constant in CQ in a way that the id's are unique even with multiple concurrent request?

Answer (score 0):

Use a service that provides you with the ID and that manages the counter inside a volatile instance variable to make sure that state changes by one thread are immediately communicated to all other threads.

This should do the trick as long as your can guarantee that your implementation runs on a single author node. In a cluster scenario you additionally have to care about executing it only on one node.

Comment: As you say, this scenario in cluster needs special handling. Is there a way to make sure an http endpoint that is called is executed only in master (through some http parameter or something)? I'm thinking that way the slave nodes can call the master which can be a single point for creating this unique id

Comment: In a clustered scenario one typically uses a loadbalancer in front to spread the load among authoring nodes. 
So this would be the place where I would make sure that any kind of of post requests with a particular parameter would be directed to the master.
Else having a kind of gateway proxy or webserver would do the trick as well.

Answer (score 0):

i'd suggest creating a service that manages its counters somewhere in the repository, and also acts as a jcr EventListener. the service should listen for NODE_ADDED events on parent nodes of type cq:Page, and once onEvent is called, it can assigned the unique id at that point. you'd want to use synchronization obviously so that overlapping calls to onEvent() won't use up the same id.

Comment: I like the idea of keeping the counter in repository. But the id generator service listening to Node_Added sounds like the uniqueId can get created only after the Page is created, whereas my use case is that the page needs to be created with page name/uri being the uniqueId.

Comment: @Shan25 have you found a solution? what about creating a service that creates a node and assigns a uid property at that time, and then returns the node to the caller?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a GUID, Graphic User ID, the ID generated has a great probablity of uniqueness.
See wiki reference http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier
and to create GUID:
[Create a GUID in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982748/create-a-guid-in-java)

This will ease you effort to verify the number is unique so just generate the ID and create the pages with that ID.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't AEM automatically append numbers to same name pages?

If it doesn't, then presumably this would fail, at which point you start over with the next number. Best guess should be enough in this case.