# how to create GUID in java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

i want to know how to create GUID number in java ee , i am using jboss 4.2.3

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate UUID in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325443/generate-uuid-in-java)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
import java.util.UUID;

UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

String randomUUIDString = uuid.toString();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.util.UUID;

...
UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
```

When identifiers are used solely within a database, their generation should be left to the database itself. [See Statement.getGeneratedKeys](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys%28%29)

[UUID Javadoc](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html)

Answer (score 1):

To generate UUID in Java you can use the [java.util.UUID](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) class. This class was introduced in JDK 1.5

```
import java.util.UUID;

UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
String randomUUIDString = uuid.toString();
System.out.println("Random UUID String = " + randomUUIDString);
System.out.println("UUID version       = " + uuid.version());
System.out.println("UUID variant       = " + uuid.variant());
```