# How to generate shorter UUIDs of 8 characters in length instead of 32 characters?

Tags: java, uuid

UUID libraries generate 32-character UUIDs.  How do I generate 8-character only UUIDs?

Comment: Sure. But it's propably not as straightforward and shorter equals less likely to be actually unique. So why?

Comment: @delnan, to be used in embedded environment?

Comment: If the resulting string can be stored in UTF-8 you potentially have 4 bytes per character. If you can use that whole range you would only need 4 UTF-8 characters to represent the same information.

Comment: why not use SQL uuid and take only first 8 characters? The other are the same for every ID.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

**It is not possible since a UUID is a 16-byte number per definition.** But of course, you can generate 8-character long unique strings (see the other answers).

Also be careful with generating longer UUIDs and substring-ing them, since some parts of the ID may contain fixed bytes (e.g. this is the case with MAC, DCE and MD5 UUIDs).

Comment: how about timestamp

Answer (score 93):

You can try `RandomStringUtils` [class from apache.commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html):

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;

final int SHORT_ID_LENGTH = 8;

// all possible unicode characters
String shortId = RandomStringUtils.random(SHORT_ID_LENGTH);
```

Please keep in mind, that it will contain all possible characters which is neither URL nor human friendly.

So check out other methods too:

```
// HEX: 0-9, a-f. For example: 6587fddb, c0f182c1
shortId = RandomStringUtils.random(8, "0123456789abcdef"); 

// a-z, A-Z. For example: eRkgbzeF, MFcWSksx
shortId = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(8); 

// 0-9. For example: 76091014, 03771122
shortId = RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(8); 

// a-z, A-Z, 0-9. For example: WRMcpIk7, s57JwCVA
shortId = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(8);
```

As others said probability of id collision with smaller id can be significant. Check out how [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) applies to your case. You can find nice explanation how to calculate approximation in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889538/probability-of-collision-with-randomly-generated-id).

Comment: Since `org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils` is deprecated, you'd be better using `org.apache.commons.text.RandomStringGenerator` in https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/

Comment: Added a new answer for `RandomStringGenerator`, as it is quite different code.

Comment: Just an FYI for the future viewers, Randomness doesn't guarantee uniqueness. Random generators guarantee randomness; and can produce a valid set of random numbers with repeat values.

Comment: `RandomStringUtils` is NOT deprecated. It's intended for simple use. Can you provide a source of the information that `RandomStringUtils` is deprecated? I can provide the documentation of the latest version of `RandomStringUtils` as a proof that it is not deprecated: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.9/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html

Comment: Only by checking a map or hashset with already used uuids, probability for collision is huge.

Comment: Okay answer, but awesome value in that last link. Thank you!

Answer (score 27):

First: Even the unique IDs generated by java UUID.randomUUID or .net GUID are not 100% unique. Especialy UUID.randomUUID is "only" a 128 bit (secure) random value. So if you reduce it to 64 bit, 32 bit, 16 bit (or even 1 bit) then it becomes simply less unique.

So it is at least a risk based decisions, how long your uuid must be.

Second: I assume that when you talk about "only 8 characters" you mean a String of 8 normal printable characters.

If you want a unique string with length 8 printable characters you could use a base64 encoding. This means 6bit per char, so you get 48bit in total (possible not very unique - but maybe it is ok for you application)

So the way is simple: create a 6 byte random array

```
 SecureRandom rand;
 // ...
 byte[] randomBytes = new byte[16];
 rand.nextBytes(randomBytes);
```

And then transform it to a Base64 String, for example by `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64`

BTW: it depends on your application if there is a better way to create "uuid" then by random. (If you create a the UUIDs only once per second, then it is a good idea to add a time stamp)
(By the way: if you combine (xor) two random values, the result is always at least as random as the most random of the both).

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but the point stands - java's UUID and .net's GUID are 100% unique. You, and the rest of the universe, will quite simply never have a uuid collision. Even if you encountered over 100 trillion UUIDs, the likelihood of a collision is still less than 1 in a billion. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Collisions

Comment: "One in a billion" is not never though.

Answer (score 11):

As @Cephalopod stated it isn't possible but you can shorten a UUID to 22 characters

```
public static String encodeUUIDBase64(UUID uuid) {
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[16]);
        bb.putLong(uuid.getMostSignificantBits());
        bb.putLong(uuid.getLeastSignificantBits());
        return StringUtils.trimTrailingCharacter(BaseEncoding.base64Url().encode(bb.array()), '=');
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a similar way I'm using here to generate an unique error code, based on Anton Purin answer, but relying on the more appropriate `org.apache.commons.text.RandomStringGenerator` instead of the (once, not anymore) deprecated `org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils`:

```
@Singleton
@Component
public class ErrorCodeGenerator implements Supplier<String> {

    private RandomStringGenerator errorCodeGenerator;

    public ErrorCodeGenerator() {
        errorCodeGenerator = new RandomStringGenerator.Builder()
                .withinRange('0', 'z')
                .filteredBy(t -> t >= '0' && t <= '9', t -> t >= 'A' && t <= 'Z', t -> t >= 'a' && t <= 'z')
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public String get() {
        return errorCodeGenerator.generate(8);
    }

}
```

All advices about collision still apply, please be aware of them.

Comment: `RandomStringUtils` is NOT deprecated. It's intended for simple use. Can you provide a source of the information that `RandomStringUtils` is deprecated? I can provide the documentation of the latest version of `RandomStringUtils` as a proof that it is not deprecated: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.9/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html

Comment: Well, if you dig a little bit further, you'll see that, as of the time of writing of this answer, the latest release had indeed deprecated this class: https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/commits/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.java Probably some feedback (https://user.commons.apache.narkive.com/GVBG2Ar0/commons-lang3-too-early-to-deprecate-randomstringutils-in-favor-of-randomstringgenerator) made it back. You shouldn't be using anything in `commons.lang` that is not strictly related to the language itself anyway, `commons.text` was created with a purpose.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation BrunoJCM. At the current moment `RandomStringUtils` is not deprecated and according to the references provided by you there is a good reason to keep it not deprecated, because it is much simpler to use than `RandomStringGenerator` for simple use cases. Maybe you can update your answer? If/when `RandomStringUtils` or its functionality for simple use cases will be moved to `commons.text`, then you can update your answer again, but currently it is misleading.

Comment: Added a note, but again, it's clear that Apache Commons project is moving text utils from `commons.lang` to `commons.text`, there is no reason for anyone to be using the former rather than the latter other than being using it already somewhere else. Simplicity here is rather subjective, I find my answer still very simple, and I'd never change it for something that would require Commons Lang to be imported.

Answer (score 3):

Not a UUID, but this works for me:

```
UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-","").substring(0,8)
```

Comment: this might be a problematic solution because some part of uuid might be common or repeat frequently

Comment: To make the previous comment a bit more concrete: UUID.randomUUID() creates a version 4 UUID: 'As in other UUIDs, 4 bits are used to indicate version 4, and 2 or 3 bits to indicate the variant (102 or 1102 for variants 1 and 2 respectively).' (wikipedia UUID). This leaves 121 or 122 bits for randomly generated part.

Answer (score 2):

How about this one? Actually, this code returns 13 characters max, but it shorter than UUID.

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.UUID;

/**
 * Generate short UUID (13 characters)
 * 
 * @return short UUID
 */
public static String shortUUID() {
  UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
  long l = ByteBuffer.wrap(uuid.toString().getBytes()).getLong();
  return Long.toString(l, Character.MAX_RADIX);
}
```

Comment: You know that `getLong()` is only reading the first 8 bytes of the buffer. The UUID will have at least 36 bytes. Am I missing something because to me this would never work.

Comment: The first 8 bytes is the most significant bits of UUID. according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/325457/851344) the less significant bits is more random. So `Long.toString(uuid.getLessSignificantBits(), Character.MAX_RADIX)` is better.

Comment: I tried this solution but it fails on adding this shortUUID in a set with 2M entries. so i will not recommend this one.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I want timestamp based shorter unique identifier, hence tried the below program.

It is guessable with `nanosecond + ( endians.length * endians.length )` combinations.

```
public class TimStampShorterUUID {

    private static final Character [] endians = 
           {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 
            'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 
            'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 
            'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 
            'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 
            'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
            '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'
            };

   private static ThreadLocal<Character> threadLocal =  new ThreadLocal<Character>();

   private static AtomicLong iterator = new AtomicLong(-1);


    public static String generateShorterTxnId() {
        // Keep this as secure random when we want more secure, in distributed systems
        int firstLetter = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, (endians.length));

        //Sometimes your randomness and timestamp will be same value,
        //when multiple threads are trying at the same nano second
        //time hence to differentiate it, utilize the threads requesting
        //for this value, the possible unique thread numbers == endians.length
        Character secondLetter = threadLocal.get();
        if (secondLetter == null) {
            synchronized (threadLocal) {
                if (secondLetter == null) {
                    threadLocal.set(endians[(int) (iterator.incrementAndGet() % endians.length)]);
                }
            }
            secondLetter = threadLocal.get();
        }
        return "" + endians[firstLetter] + secondLetter + System.nanoTime();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, String> uniqueKeysTestMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

        Thread t1 = new Thread() {  
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    String time = generateShorterTxnId();
                    String result = uniqueKeysTestMap.put(time, "");
                    if(result != null) {
                        System.out.println("failed! - " + time);
                    }
                }
            }       
        };

        Thread t2 = new Thread() {  
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    String time = generateShorterTxnId();
                    String result = uniqueKeysTestMap.put(time, "");
                    if(result != null) {
                        System.out.println("failed! - " + time);
                    }
                }
            }       
        };

        Thread t3 = new Thread() {  
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    String time = generateShorterTxnId();
                    String result = uniqueKeysTestMap.put(time, "");
                    if(result != null) {
                        System.out.println("failed! - " + time);
                    }
                }
            }       
        };

        Thread t4 = new Thread() {  
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    String time = generateShorterTxnId();
                    String result = uniqueKeysTestMap.put(time, "");
                    if(result != null) {
                        System.out.println("failed! - " + time);
                    }
                }
            }       
        };

        Thread t5 = new Thread() {  
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    String time = generateShorterTxnId();
                    String result = uniqueKeysTestMap.put(time, "");
                    if(result != null) {
                        System.out.println("failed! - " + time);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        Thread t6 = new Thread() {  
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    String time = generateShorterTxnId();
                    String result = uniqueKeysTestMap.put(time, "");
                    if(result != null) {
                        System.out.println("failed! - " + time);
                    }
                }
            }   
        };

        Thread t7 = new Thread() {  
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    String time = generateShorterTxnId();
                    String result = uniqueKeysTestMap.put(time, "");
                    if(result != null) {
                        System.out.println("failed! - " + time);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t4.start();
        t5.start();
        t6.start();
        t7.start();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: This code will work on single JVM, but we should think on distributed JVM, hence i am thinking two solutions one with DB and another one without DB.

with DB

Company name (shortname 3 chars) ---- Random_Number ---- Key specific redis COUNTER 
(3 char) ------------------------------------------------ (2 char) ---------------- (11 char)

without DB

IPADDRESS ---- THREAD_NUMBER ---- INCR_NUMBER ---- epoch milliseconds 
(5 chars) ----------------- (2char) ----------------------- (2 char) ----------------- (6 char)

will update you once coding is done.

Answer (score -14):

I do not think that it is possible but you have a good workaround.

1. cut the end of your UUID using substring()
2. use code `new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()).nextInt(99999999);`
   this will generate random ID up to 8 characters long.
3. generate alphanumeric id:

   ```
   char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABSDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890".toCharArray();
   Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
   char[] id = new char[8];
   for (int i = 0;  i < 8;  i++) {
       id[i] = chars[r.nextInt(chars.length)];
   }
   return new String(id);
   ```

Comment: Unfortunately, all of these approaches are likely to give you repeats (i.e. non-unique Ids) sooner than you want.

Comment: Isn't seeding with current date less random than using the empty constructor?