# Java UUID Compress & Decompress back

Tags: java, uuid

I would like to do the following...

a) Compress a generated UUID to String of length 8.

b) Decompress the compressed UUID back to the original UUID.

The reason is because I have to send the UUID to a partnering system, and the partnering system only accepts 8 chars for UUID, and no I cannot request for a change to the partnering system.

So, what is left to do is to compress UUID that I have to 8 char string and then decompress it back to the original UUID when a message is gotten back from the partnering system.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Java UUID's are 128-bits, so 16 x 8 bytes. Do you know of a compression algorithm that does, 100% of the time, 50% compression?

Comment: By 8 chars, do you mean 8 bytes (8x8 bits for a total of 64 bits)? Is the limit on the total size of the data sent, is it confined by a specific data format, or is it something else?

Answer (score 10):

What you ask is impossible for information-theoretic reasons.

UUIDs as specified by [RFC 4122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt) are 128 bits, as are [`UUID` objects in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html).

Java `String`s can store 16 bits per character, which *would* make for an 8-`char` string. However, *not all bit sequences are valid UTF-16 strings*, so in 8 characters you can store fewer than 128 bits of information.

So if you compress a UUID to a valid 8-character string, you have lost information, so in general there's no way to decompress it to retrieve the original UUID back.

What you might have intended is to generate a shorter string to use as a unique identifier. If so, see [Generating 8-character only UUIDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267475/generating-uuid-but-only-for-8-characters).

Answer (score 5):

The best way to achieve url safe uuid compression is to encode it in base64

```
public class UUIDUtils {

  public static String compress(UUID uuid) {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.BYTES * 2);
    bb.putLong(uuid.getMostSignificantBits());
    bb.putLong(uuid.getLeastSignificantBits());
    byte[] array = bb.array();
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(array);
  }

  public static UUID decompress(String compressUUID) {
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(Base64.getDecoder().decode(compressUUID));
    return new UUID(byteBuffer.getLong(), byteBuffer.getLong());
  }


}
```

Result: 6227185c-b25b-4497-b821-ba4f8d1fb9a1 -> YicYXLJbRJe4IbpPjR+5oQ==

Comment: Are these compressed versions more vulnerable to collisions? For those who are lazy, that's 36 characters down to 24.

Comment: No, it's not more vulnerable to a collision because it's the same thing but encode on Base64

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the UUID into a String which is really a sequence of 16-bit `char` 8 elements long as follows.

```
static String encodeUuid(final UUID id) {
  final long hi = id.getMostSignificantBits();
  final long lo = id.getLeastSignificantBits();
  return new String(new char[] {
    (char) ((hi >>> 48) & 0xffff), (char) ((hi >>> 32) & 0xffff),
    (char) ((hi >>> 16) & 0xffff), (char) ((hi       ) & 0xffff),
    (char) ((lo >>> 48) & 0xffff), (char) ((lo >>> 32) & 0xffff),
    (char) ((lo >>> 16) & 0xffff), (char) ((lo       ) & 0xffff)
  });
}

static UUID decodeUuid(final String enc) {
  final char[] cs = enc.toCharArray();
  return new UUID(
    (long) cs[0] << 48 | (long) cs[1] << 32 | (long) cs[2] << 16 | (long) cs[3],
    (long) cs[4] << 48 | (long) cs[5] << 32 | (long) cs[6] << 16 | (long) cs[7]
  );
}
```

This code indeed seems like it should work (try it yourself [here](http://ideone.com/J7tHB)), and can be encoded/decoded using both UTF-8 and UTF-16 without issue the majority of the time:

```
static boolean validate(final UUID id, final Charset cs) {
  final ByteBuffer buf = cs.encode(encodeUuid(id));
  final UUID _id = decodeUuid(cs.decode(buf).toString());
  return id.equals(_id);
}

public static void main(final String[] argv) {
  final UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
  assert validate(id, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)  : "failed using utf-8";
  assert validate(id, StandardCharsets.UTF_16) : "failed using utf-16";
}
```

---

```
C:\dev\scrap>javac UuidTest.java

C:\dev\scrap>java -ea UuidTest
```

However there is indeed the problem that some UTF-16 code points are reserved as surrogates. In the case this happens, the encoding will not work and you will be unable to reconstruct the original UUID. Refer to Mechanical snail's response above for more information on that.

---

The only data you can consistently actually *remove* from an encoded UUID generated via [UUID.randomUUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID%28%29) are those 2 used for `variant` (always `2`) and the 4 bits used for `version` (always `4`).

> There exist different variants of these global identifiers. The methods of this class are for manipulating the Leach-Salz variant, although the constructors allow the creation of any variant of UUID (described below).
>
> The layout of a variant 2 (Leach-Salz) UUID is as follows: The most significant long consists of the following unsigned fields:
>   `0xFFFFFFFF00000000 time_low
>
>    0x00000000FFFF0000 time_mid
>
>    0x000000000000F000 version
>
>    0x0000000000000FFF time_hi`
>
> The least significant long consists of the following unsigned fields:
>   `0xC000000000000000 variant
>
>    0x3FFF000000000000 clock_seq
>
>    0x0000FFFFFFFFFFFF node`
>
> The variant field contains a value which identifies the layout of the `UUID`. The bit layout described above is valid only for a `UUID` with a variant value of 2, which indicates the *Leach-Salz* variant.
>
> The version field holds a value that describes the type of this `UUID`. There are four different basic types of UUIDs: time-based, DCE security, name-based, and randomly generated UUIDs. These types have a version value of 1, 2, 3 and 4, respectively.

Comment: But the resulting string might have bogus combinations of surrogates, so you can't count on it being transmitted properly.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail I have posted example code which works. Can you give an example of where this would fail?

Comment: If any of the 16-bit blocks is in {0xFDD0, ..., 0xFDEF, 0xFFFE, 0xFFFF}, the output contains a non-character. If any is in {0xD800, ..., 0xDFFF}, the output is almost certain to contain an invalid UTF-16 sequence. In either case, in transmission all bets are off.

Comment: In particular, I think a compliant UTF-8 encoder will barf on that input.