# Generating a order number in android

Tags: android, android-activity, shopping-cart

I'm confused about how to generate a unique number as a order number which is not replicated in my mysql database.
is there any function or class to generate unique order number

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use the row id after you insert it into your database -- that way the db will handle keeping it unique.

Comment: there is a UUID class that does that sort of things. otherwise sqlite maintain a unique id of all entries.

Comment: Thanks Guys i Appreciate the reply that helped me generate unique ids or order no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://kodejava.org/how-do-i-generate-uuid-guid-in-java/) is a little example of how to use UUID, UUID can generate a unique identifier for you

Comment: The String it generates is very big. Is there any other way!!??

Comment: @RajnishSharma UUID by definition is supposed to be 16-byte. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4267848/2657670 you can try https://stackoverflow.com/a/45055701/2657670