# Java program to generate a unique and random six alpha numeric code

Tags: java, encryption, uuid

I need to generate a reservation code of 6 alpha numeric characters, that is random and unique in java.

Tried using `UUID.randomuuid().toString()`, However the id is too long and the requirement demands that it should only be 6 characters.

What approaches are possible to achieve this?

Just to clarify, (Since this question is getting marked as duplicate).
The other solutions I've found are simply generating random characters, which is not enough in this case. I need to reasonably ensure that a random code is not generated again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate a random alpha-numeric string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107/how-to-generate-a-random-alpha-numeric-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using the `hashids` library to generate salted hashes of integers (your database ids or other random integers which is probably better).

http://hashids.org/java/

```
Hashids hashids = new Hashids("this is my salt",6);
String id = hashids.encode(1, 2, 3);
long[] numbers = hashids.decode(id);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have 36 characters in the alphanumeric character set (0-9 digits + a-z letters). With 6 places you achieve 36<sup>6</sup> = 2.176.782.336 different options, that is slightly larger than 2<sup>31</sup>.

Therefore you can use [Unix time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732034/getting-unixtime-in-java) to create a unique ID. However, you must assure that no ID generated within the same second.

If you cannot guarantee that, you end up with a (synchronized) **counter** within your class. Also, if you want to survive a JVM restart, you should save the current value (e.g. to a database, file, etc. whatever options you have).

Answer (score 1):

Despite its name, UUIDs are not unique. It's simply extremely unlikely to get a 128 bit collision. With 6 (less than 32 bit) it's very likely that you get a collision if you just hash stuff or generate a random string.

If the uniqueness constraint is necessary then you need to

1. generate a random 6 character string
2. Check if you generated that string before by querying your database
3. If you generated it before, go back to 1

Another way would be to use a pseadorandom permutation (PRP) of size 32 bit. Block ciphers are modeled as PRP functions, but there aren't many that support 32 bit block sizes. Some are Speck by the NSA and the Hasty Pudding Cipher.

With a PRP you could for example take an already unique value like your database primary key and encrypt it with the block cipher. If the input is not bigger than 32 bit then the output will still be unique.

Then you would run Base62 (or at least Base 41) over the output and remove the padding characters to get a 6 character output.

Answer (score 0):

if you do a substring that value may not be unique

for more info please see following similar link
[Generating 8-character only UUIDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267475/generating-uuid-but-only-for-8-characters)

Comment: Thanks, but the requirement is strict, it has to be 6 characters. Moreover none these solutions in the link seems secure enough. I know it cant be secured 100%, so i would prefer something thats already tried and tested.

Comment: @Mishal Harish What do you mean by secure enough?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your corpus is the collection of alpha numberic letters. `a-zA-Z0-9`.

```
char[] corpus = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".toCharArray();
```

We can use `SecureRandom` to generate a seed, which will ask the OS for entropy, depending on the os. The trick here is to keep a uniform distribution, each byte has 255 values, but we only need around 62 so I will propose rejection sampling.

```
int generated = 0;
int desired=6;
char[] result= new char[desired];

while(generated<desired){
    byte[] ran = SecureRandom.getSeed(desired);
    for(byte b: ran){
       if(b>=0&&b<corpus.length){
           result[generated] = corpus[b];
           generated+=1;
           if(generated==desired) break;
       }
    }
}
```

Improvements could include, smarter wrapping of generated values.

When can we expect a repeat? Lets stick with the corpus of 62 and **assume** that the distribution is completely random. In that case we have the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem). That gives us *N = 62^6* possiblities. We want to find *n* where the chance of a repeat around 10%.

```
p(r)= 1 - N!/(N^n (N-n)!)
```

And using the approximation given in the wikipedia page.

```
n = sqrt(-ln(0.9)2N)
```

Which gives us about 109000 numbers for 10% chance. For a 0.1% chance it woul take about 10000 numbers.

Comment: This is such a random solution that OP had excluded, doesn't guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: @GaborSch "_I need to reasonably ensure that a random code is not generated again._" This is about as close to completely random, which would be _reasonably unique_ . The op hasn't really clarified. Probably the best result would be to use the current time stamp, and hash it to characters. That way it would be unique, but less random.

Answer (score -3):

you can trying to make substring out of your generated UUID.

```
String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
System.out.println("uuid = " + uuid.substring(0,5);
```

Comment: This option doesn't ensure the values aren't reused