# How can i generate unique number as format XXXX-XXXX-XXXX using c#

Tags: c#

I want to generate number as format above and I try to use `UUID()` and `GUID()` but it is not what I want(difference format and it is hexadecimal not number)

anyone have any idea or logic to do it?

Comment: Well, "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX" is only going to be unique **once**. When you say number, do you *really* mean number? So `1234-5678-9123` is a valid such number but `ABCD-1234-5678` is *not*?

Comment: GUID are already not 100% guaranteed to be unique, and you're removing quite a bit of cardinality, making it even worse. Might not be possible with that format, unless you store all the values that are already in use and then check against the list.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Maybe generating 3 unique 4 digit numbers and concatenating?

Comment: Is `0000-0000-0000` a valid number?

Comment: Are you familiar with [`RandomNumberGenerator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator(v=vs.110).aspx)or [`Random`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/en-en/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx)? You'll have to format it yourself.

Comment: here something familiar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267475/generating-8-character-only-uuids

Comment: Since this has come up several times now: Are you looking for a **unique** or a **random** number? If **unique**: **deterministic** or **chaotic**?

Comment: @jdweng Not only it that the same basic idea as the just deleted answer by Lasse, it's also wrong.

Comment: Why are you saying it is wrong.  It meets the requirements.

Comment: Random rand = new Random();
            string number = rand.Next(0, 1000000).ToString() + rand.Next(0, 1000000).ToString();
            number = number.Substring(0, 3) + "-" + number.Substring(4, 4) + "-" + number.Substring(8, 4);

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to generate 1000000000000 unique numbers is just an ever-increasing sequence:

```
long i = 42; // whatever
string key = $"{i / 100000000:0000}-{(i / 10000) % 10000:0000}-{i % 10000:0000}";
```

The next time, increase `i` before generating the key.

Comment: That does not guarantee uniqueness, it just generates pseudo-random numbers for each part of the string. It's unlikely to repeat keys, but it is possible.