# get UUID of 8 characters

Tags: python, mariadb, uuid

How to get uuid of 8 characters only?
I did the code line below and got uuid of 36 characters.

```
id1 = str(uuid.uuid1())
```

Comment: A UUID is a 128-bit value; what you see is just one possible representation of that value, namely one using ascii characters only.

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "character", what you want ranges from awkward to impossible. A UUID is a 16-byte entity, so each of the 8 "characters" has to be capable of representing a 16-bit entity, something that could have 65536 different "values".

Comment: Consider MySQL's `uuid_short()`.  I think it gives you a 64-bit number.

Answer (score 3):

### Correct answer

The correct answer to this question, as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267475/generating-8-character-only-uuids) is that **it is impossible to generate an 8 character uuid, because uuids are 16 bytes by definition.**

The standard for UUIDs is specified in [RFC 4221](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122). In the [format section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122#section-4.1), the first words are:

> The UUID format is 16 octets

Thank you [shudipta-sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7016115/shudipta-sharma) for noting that my original answer would NOT produce a universally unique id.

### Old (and incorrect) answer

<s>You could just take the first eight characters.</s>

<s>```python
id1 = str(uuid.uuid1())[:8]
```</s>

<s>No guarantees about them all being unique.</s>

Comment: This may arise collision you know @kimbo

Comment: Please read my answer again - `No guarantees about them all being unique.`

Comment: Since the op asked for a **`uuid`** (Universally Unique ID), then why you have posted an answer that does not ensure a uuid?

Comment: there's also no guarantees about actual uuids being unique

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```py
import string, random

# ''.join() joins the letters from random.choices() into a single Python str of length k.
join=''.join
join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters, k=8)) # Output is like as 'XDCxVAJl'
```

> Resource: Python’s [string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) module contains a number of useful constants: ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase, string.punctuation, ascii_whitespace, string.hexdigits and a handful of others.

Ref: https://realpython.com/python-random/

Comment: That's just a random 8-character string, not a UUID.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, assuming you only want the first 8 characters regardless of object type (python3):

```
import uuid
id1 = str(uuid.uuid1())
first_eight=id1[:8]
print(first_eight)
```