# Seed a random generator without time in java cross-plateform-ably

Tags: java, random

I'm initializing two random number generators on two threads almost simultaneously and I want the two generators behaves completely different. I will call `Random.nextInt(7)` on two generators one right after another very often. Using `System.currentTimeMillis()` is not a good idea because it looks like my computer is so fast that there's a large chance that the number I get from the two generators are the same. So is there any way to config the `Random` so that though they are called one right after another, they still behave differently? I want the solution to be cross-platform compatible so any platform-specific idea such as read from `/dev/random` is not acceptable. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way: Seed each Random instance with a UUID (GUID) converted (hashed? but probably not just a cast) to a long.

- [Generate UUID in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325443/generate-uuid-in-java)

Other answers suggest using [nanoTime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29), which may be suitable depending on the speed of the hardware, but I prefer the UUID route.

Comment: whats GUID ? where to get that from?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `System.nanoTime()` which will reduce the likelihood that both threads with have the same seed.

Or create a thread-safe utility class to get for you the random number object while ensuring that it uses a different seed for each new instance.

Also, you can assign for each thread a *numeric id* as the thread name and append it to the seed

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`SecureRandom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) to generate seeds for your two random number generators. It uses a service provider infrastructure which can use platform-specific entropy sources, so on systems where it is available, you'll likely get entropy from `/dev/random` without having to worry about it in your code. The [UUID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14804828/1468366) mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14804828/1468366) is generated from such a source, at least [in OpenJDK 7.6](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/util/UUID.java).

That said, notice that since Java 7, the preferred way to use PRNGs in multiple threads is [`ThreadLocalRandom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html). I'm not sure but it seems to me that the main goal here is avoiding synchronization overhead, not seeding issues. At least in OpenJDK 7.6, the [constructor](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.java) uses the [default `Random` constructor](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/util/Random.java), which in turn uses the high-resolution system time (given in nanoseconds, but not neccessarily with that actual resolution), combined with the current value of a static variable. The latter ensures different seeds even for instances created during the same tick of the system clock, so your original problem should be gone even when simply constructing `Random` instances using the default constructor.

This uniquification was [introduced](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/rev/df4d3e3e465a) in 2010, in response to [bug report #6937857](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6937857). The report was reported against Java 7 and was also fixed in Java 7, but according to the mercurial repository, this change should have been first included in the [`jdk7-b94` release](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/log/cf44386c8fe3).

Comment: A solution that works on Oracle java 1.6 would have more value.

Comment: @AlexWien: The service provider interface for `SecureRandom` dates from Java 1.2. I don't have the sources for that, so I don't know what exactly they are using behind the scenes, but my Oracle Java 1.6 ships with a `java.security` file which contains the line `securerandom.source=file:/dev/urandom`. Pretty strong indication that my first paragraph applies to Java 1.6 as well, just as I'd have expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.nanoTime()`, instead of `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Just delay the creation of the second thread by 30ms, that will cause nanoTime() to be randomly differnet from nanoTime() of thread1

So there is one practical view of your question, for this view nanoTime() i consider sufficient.

The other view, is a more theoretical for military safe enryption. There you want to use special hardware that use physical randomness (random registers). But that is not your intention.

Comment: There is still a likelyhood (although reduced) of the same starting seed.

Comment: I dont think so, the nano time is not an absolute time, it is the time in nano seconds since power up of the processor, and when your system starts, it accesses, hard disk, with slighty mechanical random access speeds. So when you java programm is up, the nanoTime is random.

Comment: Matt is talking about 2 threads calling get nanoTime() very qclose together  and receiving the same time...

Comment: @MitchWheat Yes, then simply create two instances of Random(), start one thread and create random object with seed = nanos, then wait 100ms, and create next Random Object with seed = nano; 100ms are never exact, so it will be random, too. ready.

Comment: kinda defeats the purpose. You could apply the same logic to posters original scenario just with a longer wait time...

Comment: @MitchWheat yes, you even dont need a seed, because since java 1.6 Random uses nanoTime as seed.

Comment: Quoting [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29): “This method provides nanosecond precision, but not necessarily nanosecond resolution (that is, how frequently the value changes) - no guarantees are made except that the resolution is at least as good as that of `currentTimeMillis()`.” So although most desktop computers will provide higher resolution that milliseconds, and thus conflicts are less likely, there are no guarantees, particularly when it comes to embedded devices and the likes.

Comment: And what? what do you think that SecureRandom uses? some magic? they use nanoTime, too.

Comment: In OpenJDK 7, `SecureRandom` will use [`/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom`](http://tinyurl.com/awa463q) on *nix and [`CryptGenRandom`](http://tinyurl.com/bh5txtx) on windows, falling back to a [static seeder in the fallback impl](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/sun/security/provider/SecureRandom.java). Even `Random()` does more than just use `nanoTime()`, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14926435/1468366) for details.

Answer (score 0):

#### Don't do anything. It works!

This is the code of java.util.Random:

```
public Random() {
    this(seedUniquifier() ^ System.nanoTime());
}
```

As the name says, the `seedUniquifier` makes the seed unique. It works both in a single thread and multithreaded:

```
private static long seedUniquifier() {
    // L'Ecuyer, "Tables of Linear Congruential Generators of
    // Different Sizes and Good Lattice Structure", 1999
    for (;;) {
        long current = seedUniquifier.get();
        long next = current * 181783497276652981L;
        if (seedUniquifier.compareAndSet(current, next))
            return next;
    }
}
```