# Id Generation for multiple forms

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Can anyone suggest if i use below code to generate id for my files, will it be unique always.
As 100s forms create the form at same automatically which auto populate ids in ID textbox. So it should be thread safe and If i restart the application it should not ever repeat the id which already generated before the application stop anytime.

```
  private static final AtomicLong count = new AtomicLong(0L);  
    public static String generateIdforFile()  
    {
        String timeString = Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis(), 36);
        String counterString = Long.toString(counter.incrementAndGet() % 1000, 36);
        return timeString + counterString;
    }
```

And forms are getting the Id using ClassName.generateIdforFile();

Comment: IF you have DB; then you can go for sequence so that though your APPLICATION is restarted DB still provide next sequence value.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a `UUID` for your file id? You could use something like the following:

```
public static String generateIdforFile()  {
    return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
}
```

Or do you need a (ongoing) numeric value?

If the number just has to be numeric (and not ongoing) you could use `UUID#getLeastSignificantBits()` or `UUID#getMostSignificantBits()` for the numeric value.

Quoting [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325443/generate-uuid-in-java):

> So the most significant half of your UUID contains 58 bits of
>   randomness, which means you on average need to generate 2^29 UUIDs to
>   get a collision (compared to 2^61 for the full UUID).

You will of course not be as collision secure as using the full UUID.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making method as synchronized there is no need to use `AtomicLong` variables.

Because concurrency is ensured by using synchronized keyword.

Using excessive concurrent variables hampers efficiency and performance of application.

Comment: Thanks, but can you tell will val variable give unique values always as it is getting drive from System.currentTimeMillis() and uniqueness will not hamper for Ids In any case like i asked Application restart should not regenerate any of the id which already generated before application stops.

Comment: Why not add the PID then ?

Comment: Well a combination of both System.currentTimeMillis() and PID will make it more concrete and supply us with unique values.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842/how-can-a-java-program-get-its-own-process-id

Answer (score 0):

Better use a global `AtomicLong` starting at `0L` for you entire application. Then you concatenate with `CurrentTimeMillis`.

```
static AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong(0L);

public static String generateIdforFile()  
{
    String timeString = Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis(), 36);
    String counterString = Long.toString(counter.incrementAndGet() % 1000, 36);
    return timeString + counterString;
}
```

This has greater chances to yield unique IDs, even between application restarts, provided that your app takes a bit more than some milliseconds to shutdown and restart. Note that the method is not synchronized anymore. (no need) And provided also, that you create less than a thousand files in the same millisecond. But you can't guarantee universal uniqueness.

Comment: Thanks, Sorry there can be around 1000 of file can trigger at once to get ID,that is why i applied sleep. UUID i dont want to use because of its length. Just want by using this code ID should be unique for future independent upon application/server crash and after recovery should not conflict with older file ids.

Comment: Then change the modulus to 10000 or 100000 or any power of 36, by the way. ;) Or drop the modulus altogether. This method should NOT have an explicit sleep. And by the way, I don't know any platform on which Sleep(1) is doing what you expect. Sleep releases the timeslot allocated to your thread, and does not guarantee that you get another time slot exactly 1 ms later. Just AT LEAST 1ms later (more likely 10ms or 20ms). The process I am describing guarantees uniqueness provided that the `counter` variable is not reset within the same millisecond.

Comment: Hi i have update the code, Can you tell now is it OK. Or in which scenario it can create duplicates.

Comment: No, it's not OK. You can't declare a method inside a method. The code I have given you creates duplicates if, within the same millisecond, either 1000 file IDs are requested, or the application is shutdown and restarted in less than 1ms, or if NTP corrects your system clock so that the exact same system time happens many times during the same day.