# 64 bits Unique ID that isn't sequence

Tags: java, uniqueidentifier

I need to a unique and 64-bit ID Generator?
I know that UUID is 128 bit but If exist any version of id generator in java get it to me.
It's important that the ids are not sequence.

Comment: You can always use a non-repeating pseudo-random number generator.

Comment: @HotLicks : I thought the usual interpretation of random generator period was that they didn't restart the exact same sequence, not that they didn't emit the same number?

Comment: @monocell - Depends on the RNG.  There is no single definition that encompasses everything.

Answer (score 3):

The least significant half of a UUID in Java is very unique, and that would give you a 64bit number.

```
UUID.randomUUID().getLeastSignificantBits()
```

Also see: [Likelihood of collision using most significant bits of a UUID in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325443/generate-uuid-in-java)

As pointed out in the comments, the number is not guaranteed unique, but duplications are unlikely

Comment: Not guaranteed to be unique, of course, but dupes would be "highly unlikely".

Comment: Thanks @HotLicks, I was trying to convery that, but I think my choice on grammar was not the best :)

Answer (score 0):

you could use a Blowfish encryption over a normal counter, or generate a UUID4 and xor the first and last 16 bytes.