# Generating 128 bit random key in java

Tags: java, random

I want to generate a 128 bit random key in java. I am using the following:

```
byte[] byteBucket = new byte[bytelength];
randomizer.nextBytes(byteBucket);
```

Will my byte array length be 16 as (16*8=128) or 128?

Answer (score 13):

try SecureRandom  API.

```
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
byte bytes[] = new byte[16]; // 128 bits are converted to 16 bytes;
random.nextBytes(bytes);
```

Comment: wouldn't an array length of 16 be 17 elements?

Comment: new byte[16] will contain 16 elements.  Their indices are 0 through 15

Answer (score 7):

## UUID

There is a class called [`java.util.UUID`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html), with a [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID--) to generate a [random-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29) [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). This [128-bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/128-bit) value has 122 of its bits generated randomly.

```
UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID() ;
```

Call `toString` to view the value as a hex string in canonical format with hyphens inserted.

> uuid.toString(): 24b47cf5-fb53-4fb1-a5a2-8b415260304d

You can extract the 128 bits as a pair of 64-bit `long` integer numbers. Call [`getMostSignificantBits()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#getMostSignificantBits--) and [`getLeastSignificantBits()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#getLeastSignificantBits--).

```
long mostSignificant = uuid.getMostSignificantBits() ;
long leastSignificant = uuid.getLeastSignificantBits() ;
```

This value may not be appropriate for critical security applications with 4 bits being predictable (not random). But in other practical applications, this handy class may work well.

Here is a question which I found on SO with more detailed explanation: [Likelihood of collision using most significant bits of a UUID in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325443/generate-uuid-in-java)

Comment: `java.util.UUID/randomUUID` is not suitable for general purpose 128 bit random number generation, since it only generates 122 random bits. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29

Comment: @DavidJames Please explain more as it is mentioned in the javadocs for UUID "A class that represents an immutable universally unique identifier (UUID). A UUID represents a 128-bit value." I understand that it actually generates 122 bits only. but its also unique across the world isn't it?

Comment: Both comments are correct: In a random-based UUID only, 122 of the 128 bits is randomly generated. So technically not meeting the 128-bits of randomness asked in the Question. But practically speaking, in real-world work, both have have about the same chance of collisions: virtually nil. For critical security applications, the random UUID may not be appropriate, but for other non-critical applications the random UUID works well and is handy with just a short line of code using built-in Java class.