# Unique strings in java

Tags: java, string, uniqueidentifier

Is there a function in Java that takes in two strings and generates one 16 character string which is unique to the given combination? I dont expect the string to be 100% unique as long as the probability of having 2 conflicting strings is very small (1 in 100,000 for example). Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate UUID in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325443/generate-uuid-in-java)

Comment: Concatenate the strings, then hash the combined string using SHA-1 or similar?

Comment: could you give us some example?

Comment: read about MessageDigest

Comment: Thank you for all. I ended up using the method proposed by DNA.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate both strings and hash them.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you meant `concatenate`, but I can't edit your post, as changing this one word is too little change.

Comment: True story. That was typo.

Answer (score 0):

If it needs to be *truly* unique, then a concatenation of the strings which is 16 characters or less is your answer.

Else you have to rely on hashing. But that comes with no guarantee of a probability of clashing.

Your best bet is to use a GUID.