# How can I write an if statement stating image in imageView is equal to image in imageButton?(Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, image, android-studio, imageview

I am attempting to make a short term memory game, where there is an initial imageButton, when clicked disappears and shows the user 4 options. The user should pick the correct picture(I will do this with if statement). My problem is connecting the image in imageButton to the correct image in one of the imageViews.

The images are randomized in imageView. The images are taken from a database.

```
public void A1(View v){


        if(v.getId()==pic1.getId()){
            aOne(v);
        }else if(v.getId()==pic2.getId()){
            aTwo(v);
        }else if(v.getId()==pic3.getId()){
            aThree(v);
        }else if(v.getId()==pic4.getId()){
            aFour(v);
        }

    }

    public void aOne(View v){

        if(resource in imageButton== Resource in imageView){
            pic1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            pic2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            pic3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            pic4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        if(imageButton==pic2){
            pic1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            pic2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            pic3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            pic4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }if(imageButton==pic3){
            pic1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            pic2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            pic3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            pic4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }if(imageButton==pic4){
            pic1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            pic2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            pic3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            pic4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Probably should consider creating an Object with image variable with a UUID (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325443/likelihood-of-collision-using-most-significant-bits-of-a-uuid-in-java) and set the uuid to view everytime it changes with view.setId then you can compare myObject.getUUID to view.getId

Comment: `and shows the user 4 options`. Ok, but what does the user see? Four imageviews with four different images?

Comment: Yes, that is what the user sees.